# Show the interchange of limit and integral is ok.

Tags: real-analysis

Lebesgue intergral :$\lim_{n→∞} \int_0^∞(1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}x^{-\frac{1}{n}}\mathrm{d}x$ 
I don't know how to show interchange of limit and integral is ok. I don't know how to apply the convergence theorem..

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: The sequence of functions is clearly decreasing. You can use the Lebesgue theorem on the monotone convergence

Comment: @Adam But I can't see it is decreasing...